# Example for pairwise independent, but not jointly independent on Wikipedia

Tags: probability, independence

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence, it gives an example for pairwise independency, but not joint independency.

The example is

> Suppose X and Y are two independent tosses of a fair coin, where we designate 1 for heads and 0 for tails. Let the third random variable Z be equal to 1 if exactly one of those coin tosses resulted in "heads", and 0 otherwise. Then jointly the triple (X, Y, Z) has the following probability distribution:
> $$ (X,Y,Z) = \begin{cases}(0,0,0) && \text{with probability 1/4} \\ 
> (0,1,1) && \text{with probability 1/4} \\ 
> (1,0,1) && \text{with probability 1/4} \\ 
> (1,1,0) && \text{with probability 1/4} \\ 
> \end{cases}$$

I am confused why $X,Y,Z$ is pairwise independent. Doesn't information about $X$ and $Y$ give information about $Z$? For example, if we know $X = 1$ or $Y = 1$, then surely $Z = 1$.

Comment: Pairwise independence means that you consider each of the three pairs $(X,Y)$, $(X,Z)$, $(Y,Z)$ separately.

Comment: Yes, "information about *both* $X$ and $Y$ gives information about $Z$."  However, information only about $X$, e.g. suppose you are told what $X$ is, gives no information about $Z$ alone.

Comment: Your argument is indeed why it is not jointly independent. Pairwise dependent means that there is no dependency between a pair. Thus all pairs are independent, e.g. $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $X$ is independent of $Z$, but $X, Y$ and $Z$ are not jointly independent.

Comment: @lulu I understand that, but isn't (X,Z) and (Y,Z) here dependent?

Comment: @SherwinLott Ah. This is distinction that I missed, that BOTH (X,Y) is required to give information about $X$. But let's say you know $X$ and don't know $Y$, does this not increase/decrease the likelihood of $Z = 1$ at all?

Comment: @SherwinLott It seems in this case it does not because if $X = 1$, then $Z$ has a 50/50 chance of being 1 or 0, and the same if $X = 0$. But what if, say, the first coin (associated with X) is fair, and the second coin is strongly biased towards heads, say, 95% probability of getting heads. In that case if $X = 0$ and without knowing $Y$, then $Z$ should have a higher likelihood of being $1$ than if $X$ wasn't known?

Comment: Yes, a different set up might yield a different result.

Comment: @lamanon Exactly.  Yes, in your new example $X$ alone would be very informative about $Z$.

Comment: @SherwinLott My last question is, is the pairwise dependency definition of $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$ an IFF condition? i.e., if we find $P(A,B) = P(A) P(B)$, then this means A and B are pairwise independent, or does it only apply one way, i.e., if A and B are pairwise independent then P(A,B)=P(A)P(B), but not vice versa?

Comment: Yes, it is an if and only if definition. Events $A$ and $B$ are pairwise independent IFF $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$. Events $A$, $B$, $C \ldots$ are pairwise independent IFF this holds for all pairs. With discrete random variables, e.g. coin flips $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, are pairwise independent IFF the events $X=x$, $Y=y$, and $Z=z$ are pairwise independent for any realizations $x$, $y$, and $z$ (i.e. $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all 0 or 1 in this coin flip example).